# Setting up a Server for Android App using Google Cloud

Tags: java, android, python, google-cloud-platform

We have currently developed an android app and we wanted to create a storage space in google cloud to store the data for each user.

To do this, we have set up a python script that gets a post request from the app and it adds on to a database with the post data.

In google cloud, we have successfully set up a VM instance and through sftp we have added the script inside the VM instance.

However, we are not sure how to set up the VM instance such that when it gets a request it runs the python script and populates the database. We have used a similar combination of server side script and application side for a class project and it works as expected. But when we decided to move the idea from the class' server to google cloud we are having problems.

So we think that we need to figure out a way to generate the "VM instance URL" in order for the application to post to the VM instance. Nevertheless, we are open to any other suggestions and solutions that the community might have to offer.

We can also provide some code for reference if requested.

Thank you very much!

Comment: Did you consider using [Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/) instead? You also have the address to your VM, but you'll have to run the python script in an appropriate WSGI server - exactly how you do that depends on what framework your code is using. For testing you can probably ssh into the server and run the script as you'd do locally.

Comment: The Android app is supposed to be part of a bigger project, this is why we chose Google Cloud from the beginning. However, thank you for your suggestion, I didn't really know about Firebase, it seems to fit our needs!

Comment: If you think that `Firebase` fits your needs, please post it as an answer so we can mark this as resolved.

Comment: @MatsLindh Post your comment as an answer. The original poster has acknowledged that this fits their needs. It will be good for the community

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider [using Firebase instead](https://firebase.google.com/).

You also have the address to your VM, but you'll have to run the python script in an appropriate WSGI server - exactly how you do that depends on what framework your code is using. For testing you can probably ssh into the server and run the script as you'd do locally.